# Calculate that the difference between two teams will be in interval $[5,9]$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

We know these facts: the mean of score difference between two teams is $3.5$. The team with probability $p_1=0.5$ will win by $4,5,6$ or more points and with $p_2=0.5$ will win by $0,1,2,3$ or lose by any result. How to calculate that the difference between two teams will be in interval $[5,9]$? I think we need to use Poisson distribution because then, $variance=mean$ but I don't know how to correctly write it.

Comment: "We know these facts: the mean is $3.5$."--- the mean of *what*, exactly?

Comment: @5xum the mean of score difference between two teams.

Comment: Apparently both the mean and the median difference is $3.5$.  But without more information you cannot say anything about the probability that the difference is in $\{5,6,7,8,9\}$ except to say it is no more than $0.5$.  If you assume each score is independently Poisson distributed then the difference has a [Skellam distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution) but that does not seem to make things easier

Comment: @Henry what additional information we need that say about probability in this interval? Because in task written if you need more information write what info exactly :D